# IOS UITextView leaks undomanager

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

![I have a navigation controller and it has a root view controller.
There is a button on the root's view and once it is clicked, another controller is pushed.
The second controller's view has a textview and everything I input something to it and press back button to pop, it gets a leak. the screen shot is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH1IB.jpg)

It seems that the leak is caused by undomanager, but I did not register the textview to any undomanager.

By the way I am using ARC and the second view controller has the textView property as: `@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *descriptionTextView;`
The textView is initialized in viewDidLoad as:

```
self.descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, self.titleTextField.frame.origin.y + self.titleTextField.bounds.size.height + 10, 310, self.view.bounds.size.height - 214 - 40 - 10 - 14 - self.titleTextField.frame.origin.y - self.titleTextField.bounds.size.height)];
self.descriptionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
self.descriptionTextView.editable = YES;
self.descriptionTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.descriptionTextView.layer.borderColor = [kColor_MainColor CGColor];
self.descriptionTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0f];
self.descriptionTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.descriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.descriptionTextView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:80/255.0 green:80/255.0 blue:80/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.descriptionTextView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: You do not register the text view with an undo manager, the system does it for you, so the user can shake to undo or select undo button in the keyboard.

Comment: So how do I solve this leak?
I tried codes like removeAllActions in delloc, but it didnot work

Comment: This could be a bug with system internals. It wouldn't be the first time Apple frameworks leak. If see that you cannot solve in any other way, please make sure to open a bug report with Apple, letting them know.